# 'html template not found' error (VS Code)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, templates, visual-studio-code

I have the following files on VS code and when I try to run them on my browser, it fails to identify that there is any reg.html template at all. What is  the issue?

python file

```
from flask import  Flask, 

render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "asdfghjkl"

@app.route("/")
def form():
    return render_template("reg.html", title = "Form")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

html file (reg.html)

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login/Signup - ((title)) </title>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "(( url for('static', filename = 'css/bootstrap.min.css)' ))">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "(( url for('static', filename = 'css/site.css') ))">
 
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-5">
                <h1 class = "text-center">Registration form</h1>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
        <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.js.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src = "((url for ('static', filename = 'js/bootstrap.min.js')))">`</script>`

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why is `render_template, flash` not on line 1 ( `from`)

Comment: @rioV8 Oh um, that probably happened when I pasted sorry, but it is in line 1 in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this question, create a folder named `templates`, which is where Flask looks for templates by default, then put the reg.html in this folder:

[image]

start the program and you will observe the results:

[image]

Detailed information about flask, you can refer to [Flask Tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask).

Comment: Also, if you run the app.py from the UI, it might not have the templates folder in the path. open a terminal, cd for the app.py directory, and then run python app.py.